# How do i wait for an event in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

i was coding a game in Unity with visual scripting and i got stuck with one problem: I didn't know how to make it so that it waits until I click a key and not so that it only gives me one frame to click the key.

I've already tried using an if and connecting the false to a wait seconds that's set to 0 and connecting it to the if.
[what i've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5tuy.png)

edit: yes, the scene exists.

Comment: Well normally you dont "wait" for an event.   When the event is triggered it runs the necessary code.